# How to maintain carbide-tipped drill bits?

Tags: powertools

I used a carbide bit to drill a hole in my ceramic tile to install a grab bar in the shower stall. I left the carbide drill bit to cool before I used an old toothbrush to brush off the debris from the tip under tap water then wiped it dry with a towel.

Do I need to grease it before storing it?

Comment: When I used it on ceramic I start slow and gradually sped it up.  Hopefully it will still have a long useful life ahead.

Comment: I hate to break your heart, but drill bits that get used rarely have a long life.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lot of lubricant (water) while drilling that will prolong their life. Otherwise, they will overheat the tip (red hot) and ruin the carbide tips. That is why you must cool it during drilling so they only get mildly warm.

After that to prevent rusting you can apply some grease.

Comment: When you eventually need to sharpen them, diamond sharpening stones/paddles will do the job.

Comment: @keshlam that is correct

Comment: Red hot is not a problem for carbide. Passing 1000°C is a problem for carbide, 5-600°C is not.

Comment: @vidarlo are you sure that's true for all forms of carbide - don't some use a binder?

Comment: Note that high-speed-steel bits can drill many metals if lubricated and used properly. I put a *lot* of 1/2  holes through iron C-beams when helping refit a friend's basement to raise the ceiling a few inches, using a normal bit in a small drill press. Ceterpunching the spot before starting to drill also helps by giving the boys more positive starting point.

Answer (score 0):

What's at issue is the binder that holds the carbide sand together. Some drill bits using cheap "cobalt" binders can break down quickly if left exposed to acids. Nickel binders are pretty much faultless.

Your best practice is probably to clean well, then use some non-corossive (firearm) lube.